# Firebase data schema guidance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, schema, nosql

I am newbie to Firebase and working on to create events using firebase. Here i am inviting my friends using their phone number.(It is not necessary that whom i am inviting will be part of the system user.)

Below is my schema:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "message": "Lunch",
      "startTime": 1469471400000,
      "eventCreatorId": 1,
      "endTime": 1469471400000,
      "invitees": [
        {
          "phone": "1234567890",
          "type": "phone"
        },
        {
          "phone": "345678901",
          "type": "phone"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now problem is that how i can find list of all events for specific invites?? (i.e in above case i want to find list of all events for user with phone number eqaul to 345678901.)

Can anyone suggest good schema to handle above scenario with firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to using a NoSQL database. :-)

In NoSQL you often end up modeling the data different, to allow the queries that you want your app to execute. In this case, you apparently want to both show the invitees per event *and* the events per invitee. If that is the case, you'll store the data in both formats:

```
{
  "events": {
    "event1": {
      "message": "Lunch",
      "startTime": 1469471400000,
      "eventCreatorId": 1,
      "endTime": 1469471400000,
      "invitees": {
        "phone_1234567890": true,
        "phone_345678901": true
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "phone_1234567890": {
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "type": "phone",
      "events": {
        "event1": true
      }
    },
    "phone_345678901": {
      "phone": "345678901",
      "type": "phone"
      "events": {
        "event1": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll see that I've split your data into two separate top-level nodes: events and users. They refer to each other with so-called explicit indexes, essentially a set of foreign keys that you manage (and join) in your client-side code.

I've also replaced you arrays with named keys. If your events/users have natural keys (such as `uid` for identifying the user if you happen to use Firebase Authentication) you'd use that for the key. But otherwise, you can use Firebase push ids. Using such keys leads to a more scalable data structure then depending on array indices.

Both of these topics are covered in the [Firebase documentation on data structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data). I also highly recommend this [article on NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Hi Frank, This makes perfect sense. I thought about using denormalization here but i got bit confused. Now with above explanation and modified schema i am clear on this. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.:-)